# ReactJS Context > Reference latest state value from a state function

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently using a common `Context` pattern I've seen, which allows child components to update a parent's state (i.e. the `Provider`) by passing a modifier function down through the shared `Context`.

The problem I'm having, is that the modifier functions only reference the original state, and don't reference the latest state...

#### Is there a way to get the latest state values (i.e. `state.user`) from the modifier function (i.e. `modUser`)?

*Below is the minimum code to reproduce:*

**Expected output:** `Nick` ... then `Bob` ... then `BOB`.

**Actual output:** `Nick` ... then `Bob` ... then `NICK`.

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react"

const defaultState = {
  user: null,
  setUser: () => { },
  modUser: () => { }
}
const Context = React.createContext(defaultState)

const Test = () => {
  const setUser = user => setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user }))
  const modUser = () => setUser(state.user.toUpperCase()) // `state.user` never changes to updated value!
  // user is 'Nick' at start...
  const initState = {
    user: 'Nick',
    setUser,
    modUser
  }
  // user changes to 'Bob' after 1 second...
  useEffect(() => { setTimeout(() => setUser('Bob'), 1000) }, [])
  const [state, setState] = useState(initState)
  return <Context.Provider value={state}>
    <div>Parent user is {state.user}</div>
    <TestInner />
  </Context.Provider>
}

const TestInner = () => {
  const state = useContext(Context)
  // user (should) change to uppercase 'BOB' after 2 seconds...
  useEffect(() => { setTimeout(() => state.modUser(), 2000) }, [])
  return <div>Child user is {state.user}</div>
}

export default Test
```

Comment: You can pass a callback to the state setter, also `toUpperCase` does not mutate and even if it did you should not mutate state so your modUser should look like `const modUser = () => setUser(state=>({...state,user:state.user.toUpperCase()})) ` Since you pass modUser to several components probably wrap that in a useEffect as well: `const modUser = React.useEffect(() => setUser(state=>({...state,user:state.user.toUpperCase()})),[])`

Comment: Thanks @HMR - I think you had a typeo (`setState` instead of `setUser`), TLDR `const modUser = () => setState(state => ({ ...state, user: state.user.toUpperCase() }))` fixed it. `toUpperCase` not mutating wasn't the problem either (it was being passed to the other function). Problem was not having a reference to the updated `state` object. Also, I couldn't get `useEffect` working, it was being invoked immediately for some reason.

Comment: maybe redux would help?

Comment: ^^ how do I downvote @samw2k00 :)

Comment: @HMR - claim the solution below if you want it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback to the state setter. Looking a little closer at your code there is no need to wrap setUser or modUser in a useCallback because after `const [state, setState] = useState(initState);` you never change them. The following can work and initializes the state once so mod and setUser don't need to be re created on re render of Test (because they are only used on first render and then ignored.

```js
const { useState, useContext, useEffect } = React;
const Context = React.createContext();

const Test = () => {
  //use callback to set state with initial value, after
  //  first render the callback will not be called again
  //  until component is unmounted and re mounted
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => ({
    setUser: user =>
      setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, user })),
    modUser: () =>
      setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        user: state.user.toUpperCase(),
      })),
    user: 'Nick',
  }));
  //get the setUser function to pass it to useEffect as a dependency
  const { setUser } = state;
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setUser('Bob'), 1000);
  }, [setUser]);
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={state}>
      <div>Parent user is {state.user}</div>
      <TestInner />
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
const TestInner = () => {
  const { modUser, user } = useContext(Context);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => modUser(), 2000);
  }, [modUser]);
  return <div>Child user is {user}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```